# Jquery Validation Plugin, Use option's data element as check for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm looking for a way to have JQuery validate plugin check the value of a selected option's data element to determine if the selection is valid or invalid. The reason invalid options need to be included in the select is primarily for display purposes. i.e. if I have a select with the question "What colour is your house?" and I have options "Red", "Blue", "Green", the end user needs to be explicitly shown that "Green" is not a valid choice.

Right now I'm using 'validate' for everything else but I had to write in a separate function to check these fields and I'd like to be able to do it all with just 'validate'.

Here is a more detailed example of what I'm looking for:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-validate-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {

    // BASIC VALIDATION
    // Set Validator Defaults and rules
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {  
            $(element).attr({"title": error.append()});
        },
        highlight: function(element){
            $(element).addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element){
            $(element).removeClass("error");
        }
    });
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            myselect: {
                // HOW DO I DEFINE THIS RULE SO THAT 
                // IF OPTION 3 IS SELECTED THIS RETURNS
                // INVALID
            }
        }   
    });
});
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<form id='myform' name='myform'>
    <input type='text' id='email' name='email value='' />
    <select id='myselect' name='myselect'>
        <option id='1' data-is_valid='1'>Option 1</option>
        <option id='2' data-is_valid='1'>Option 2</option>
        <option id='3' data-is_valid='0'>Option 3</option>
        <option id='4' data-is_valid='1'>Option 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Makes no sense.  Just create the `select` so that it only contains valid options in the first place.  Typically, the very first option, the `please choose` option, contains a `value=""` which forces the user to make a selection when the `required` rule is in force.  Under what scenario would any other option be invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving it:
Thankyou to Sparky for pointing me in the right direction

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valid_option", function(value, element) {
    if ($(":selected", element).data('is_valid') == "1") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, "&nbsp&nbspError, Invalid Selection");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I had to write in a separate function to check these fields and I'd like to be able to do it all with just `validate`."*

You *could* use [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to wrap your separate function and turn it into a rule.

---

However, if you'd take the time to explain why you'd want to restrict a `select` to certain options, when you're already in control of how the `select` is created in the first place, a better answer or workaround could possibly be suggested.  (*this is one way that SO benefits everyone else long after the OP is satisfied*)

Comment: You're right, my apologies. The explanation of why I need to be able to select options that are invalid has to do with the way my company wants the form displayed. It's silly I know and if I were building it myself I would have just done it the way you suggested. In any case I did figure it out and will post the answer below. Again Sparky, sorry for being short with you.

Comment: @ajax1515, My vote is locked until you edit the question.  Maybe mention that you're creating "invalid" options for visual/layout purposes, then I'll be able to remove my down vote.